# Efficient Firestore Query for Nested Arrays with Vendor and Product Conditions

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I have a Firestore data structure with nested arrays, and I'm struggling to find an efficient way to query documents based on both vendor and product conditions within these nested arrays.

Here's a simplified version of the data structure:

```
"configurations": {
  "CVE_data_version": "4.0",
  "nodes": [

    {
      "operator": "OR",
      "children": [],
      "cpe_match": [
        {
          "vulnerable": true,
          "vendor": "redhat",
          "product": "enterprise_linux:",
          "cpe23Uri": "cpe:2.3:o:redhat:enterprise_linux:8.0:*:*:*:*:*:*:*",
          "cpe_name": []
        }
      ]
    },
    // Other nodes
  ]
}
```

I need to query documents efficiently based on the vendor and product conditions within the cpe_match array.

Query Attempt:

```
const cveQuery = query(
  cveCollectionRef,
  where('configurations.nodes', 'array-contains', {
    'cpe_match': {
      'vendor': 'redhat',
      'product': 'enterprise_linux'
    }
  })
);
```

Is there a way to query by vendor and product, nested queries?

Comment: What exactly is the desired result? What's wrong with the query you have now? Please edit the question to be clear what sort of answer you're looking for. If you're expecting Firestore to extract matching items out of a single array field in a document, you should know it doesn't do that.  Firestore query results always return entire matching documents based on the filter you provide.  If you want Firestore to filter items, each item needs to be its own document.

Comment: @DougStevenson I need to query documents efficiently based on the vendor and product conditions within the cpe_match array, create a query that queries for vendor and product.

Comment: What you're trying to do isn't possible with the document structure you have now.  Firestore can't single out nested array items by incomplete data.  You'll need each cpe_match item to be a separate document in a different collection so that you can filter them individually.

Comment: @DougStevenson yes sadly, I first implement it where I filter "potential" finds on the api side, but the problem is that it needs to get and then filter over 10k-20k data rows. This isnt really efficient and good because it slow downs the api a lot. Do know a better way?

Comment: As I said, I restructure your documents to be easier for this particular query.  This practice (modeling your data to suit your queries) is very common for nosql type databases.  If this doesn't work for you, then consider a different database.

Answer (score 1):

As I see in your document schema, the `cpe_match` is an array of custom objects. There is no way in Firestore you can query a collection based on the two properties that exist within an array of objects. You cannot query using partial data. To be able to filter the data, you should pass to the `where()` function, the entire object, and not only some partial data. The object should contain values for all the fields. Since most likely this is not what you're looking for, the simplest solution would be to get those objects out of the array and add them as @DougStevenson mentioned in his comment, as separate documents in a collection. In this way, you'll me able to chain two, or multiple `where()` calls in a single query.

Comment: Hey there. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?